# Regarding python django

Tags: python, django

error while migrating
webapp.Login.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'webapp.Login.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'auth.User.user_permissions'
models

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.
class Login(AbstractUser):
    is_student=models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Student(models.Model):
    user= models.OneToOneField(Login,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='student')
    name= models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

trying to makemigrations

Comment: [Have you tried to read the documentation regarding the issue of using Custom User model?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

Answer (score 0):

The migration failed because you have two models with the same reverse accessor name. The reverse accessor name is used when you access the related model from an instance of the current model.

You need to change one of the reverse accessor names in order for the migration to succeed. For example, you can change the reverse accessor name for the Login model from 'user_permissions' to something else, such as 'login_permissions'.